# How will libpam-poldi work with ecryptfs

Tags: pam, ecryptfs, openpgp

I'd like to authenticate myself to my machine using my PGP SmartCard. I'm under the impression that I can do this using libpam-poldi. However, I also have directories that are encrypted using ecryptfs that are decrypted when I supply my unix password.

If I use libpam-poldi to log in without requiring my user password, will ecryptfs decrypt those directories?

If not, how can I configure ecryptfs to do this?

Bonus points: Any one have good resources to learn more about PAM in general?